# Wordpress custom plugin wpdb not recognized

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm developing my first wordpress plugin where I can list all my employees with some CRUD functionality.

When I click "Add Employee" I get a new window where I can fill in all the fields for an employee and after that I click "Save"

But when I click save I get the following PHP error:

```
   Fatal error: Call to a member function insert() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\wp-custom-plugin\wp-content\plugins\werknemers\employee_crud_functions.php on line 15
```

And when I look at line 15 the code is:

```
 $wpdb->insert( ... )
```

and this is my form with the action set to that php page

```
 <form method="POST" action="<?php bloginfo('url') ?>/wp-content/plugins/werknemers/employee_crud_functions.php">
```

I assume that the file is not aware of the $wpdb variable. But how can I let that php page know what it is? Or am I using it all wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You are quite possibly missing the global declaration of `$wpdb`.

From the [wpdb reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb).

```
WordPress provides a global variable, $wpdb, 
which is an instantiation of the class already 
set up to talk to the WordPress database. 
Always use the global $wpdb variable. 
(Remember to globalize $wpdb before using it in any custom functions.)
```

You need to use it like this.

```
global $wpdb;
//do something with it.
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I declared that variable already...But in my case it's not a function, I just redirect to a page which reads my $_POST variables, do I need make a function for it and hook it in some kind of way?

Comment: It would be good if you just post the relevant code instead of us guessing. :)

Comment: I don't have the code with me now, but I was planning to do that when I'm at the computer where the code is on ;)

Answer (score 2):

Do you have your $wbdb global?
I know it's not very good practice to use global but most Wordpress plugins seem to work this way...

```
 function myFunction() {
       global $wpdb;
       $wpdb->insert(...);
    }
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I declared that variable already...But in my case it's not a function, I just redirect to a page which reads my $_POST variables, do I need make a function for it and hook it in some kind of way?

Answer (score 0):

you can include wp-config file like this 
include('../../../wp-config.php'); it works for me.
here my folder's directory structure is 
F:\wamp64\www\Wordpress\custom_plugin_development\wp-content\plugins\CRUD-Plugin